# Local http server has stopped running

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, server

I installed the NPM package and the http server in the "server" folder. Everything worked perfectly, but then suddenly the server stopped running.

When I try to start the local http server I see this error message in the terminal (console)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have anlther application running on port `8080`. Try navigating to localhost:8080 to figure out what it is and close the application.
It could even be another instance of node.

Comment: I also had that thought! I think it happened after I launched the server with the command "npm start", which I wrote in the package.json file (server was launched after that) and then I changed the script of the command and put it into the console again, without stopping the server. How can I stop the http server, downloaded using 'npm install http-server"?

Comment: localhost:8080 - blank page

Comment: so, something is definitely using port 8080 - which OS are you running

Comment: and I mean that on localhost:8080 I get a blank page and the message "connection attempt failed"

Comment: try this in the terminal `killall node`

Comment: "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: That "connection attempt failed" page, does it look like a standard browser error page ? also try this `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`

Comment: That code should have given you a list of apps currently using a tcp connection on your system with the port numbers. It shouldn't have actually terminated anything unless whatever it was crashed on its own for some other reason.

Comment: Glad you've got node back up and running either way.

Comment: It's weird, because "killall node", it seems to me, did not stop the server. But perhaps I am wrong, I will probably try to recreate this situation later to check. Thank you again!